# How can I get a part of text file by terminal

Tags: command-line

How can I get some block of text by lines?

I have a log file with 6000000 lines and I want get just a block of 607366 to 700000.

I've tried something like:

```
head -n 607366 | tail -700000 server.log > outputFile.txt
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n 607366,700000p server.log > outputFile.txt
```

If you want to use `head` and `tail`, this is the right way:

```
head -n 700000 server.log | tail -n $(echo 700000-607366+1 | bc) > outputFile.txt
```

or, shorter:

```
head -n 700000 server.log | tail -n 92635 > outputFile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the output doesn't started at line 607366 :/

Comment: @EmanuellaRamosCavalcante Please check again; I'm sure that it start from there :/

Comment: @RaduRădeanu maybe you can help with a similar question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94464/search-and-filter-text-on-large-log-files

Answer (score 2):

Optimisations on Radu's ones:

```
sed '607366,$!d;700000q' server.log > outputFile.txt
```

That way, we stop reading (`q`) `server.log` after we find the 700000<sup>th</sup> line.

```
head -n 700000 server.log | tail -n "$((700000-607366+1))"
```

No need to invoke `bc` here, we can use standard arithmetic expansion.

But doing it the other way round is going to be a lot more efficient:

```
tail -n +607366 | head -n "$((700000-607366+1))"
```

as it doesn't involve storing in memory a large number of lines.